# Dynamically Populate Navigation Bar

Tags: html, node.js

How would I go about making a navigation bar that can dynamically populate itself? For example, if I add a new page to my website, how can  I have the navigation bar reflect this by itself instead of me having to go through every single existing page and change the navigation bar code manually?

Comment: You should at least attempt to solve the problem yourself, and bring some of your code for us to help you with, otherwise it's our job to write all the code for you - which isn't the purpose of Stack Overflow. Do some research, take a crack at it, and if you still have problems bring your progress and then ask!

Comment: I'm not looking for code, more for some general suggestions on how to handle this. I'm thinking of maybe a Node.js script to read the files in a directory and then output the HTML. Would this be feasible?